# Проблема с пустым ответом python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

Есть асинхронная функция, которая отправляет запросы через API. Мне нужно делать проверку на пустой ответ, но почему-то при `print(html_3['items'] is None)` пишет `False`, хотя в ответе пустота. В чем проблема?

```
...

async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/my-inventory/?key={profiles_dict[1][1]}') as resp_3:
    html_3 = await resp_3.json()
    print(html_3['items'])
    print(html_3['items'] is None)

...
```

Ответ:

```
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[{'id': '23354298822', 'classid': '310777025', 'instanceid': '0', 'market_hash_name': 'Dual Berettas | Colony (Minimal Wear)', 'market_price': 0.69, 'tradable': 1}]
False
[]
False
[]
False
[]
False

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: None и пустота не одно и то же. Тем более, что вам явно выводится [], а не какая-то там пустота.

Comment: Так а что не так? Вы спрашиваете является ли список `None`, питон отвечает что `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте

```
len(html_3['items']) > 0
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал проверку через `if html_3['items'] is not None:` работает как нужно.

Comment: а еще лучше вот так `if not html_3['items']:`